# Running django-admin.py startproject is giving me an error

Tags: python, django, command-line, cmd

I've just started looking into python and django.. Im pretty sure ive successfull installed both python and the django framework and i managed to add python and django-admin.py to my system path but now when i run the command `django-admin.py startproject My_Test_Site`, in the folder i want to create a new project directory in (just following the tutorials), i get the following error:

[image: Command prompt screenshot of the error i'm getting]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Django error. It appears it cannot find the Python module `unicodedata` which is part of the Python Standard Library ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html)). I see that there is also a bug report about this issue (Python 2.7 on Windows, see [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue14975)). On the other hand, some people there report that reinstalling their Python installation fixed the problem. You could give that a try.

Comment: Ah thanks, I un-installed python and found an older version of python (2.7.2) to install. Then i tried exactly the same thing and it worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

notice the last line, it says import unicodedata, importError

im guessing you probably didnt install your django properly.

so reinstall it and check that django is in your "path", i believe django does this automatically when it installs but doesnt hurt to double check.

if reinstalling django still doesn't work, i suggest you uninstall python and django related stuff.

then install python, install pip, then use pip install django.